# C++ Data Timeout with Blocking Call

Tags: c++, multithreading, timeout

I have a main loop which is fully data-driven: it has a blocking call to receive data and stores it as the 'most recent' (accessed elsewhere). Each piece of data has an associated lifespan, after which the data timesout and can no longer be considered valid. Each time I receive data I reset the timeout.

Unfortunately I can currently only test the data validity when the main thread is woken by the arrival of new data. I need to be able to trigger an event if/when the data expires, *unless* I receive new data in the meantime.

Please can anyone suggest a solution?

If it helps, I have Boost v1.33.1 installed - but cannot update to a more recent version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the expiration of data is an asynchronous event, you'll need to use an asynchronous timer.  As you're using boost, you may want to look into Boost.Asio, which provides you with `deadline_timer` objects that can be used in conjunction with callback handlers.  (See [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) for more information.)  The callback handler will be invoked when the timer expires, which will allow you to check the validity of your data.

**Edit:** Ahh...I just noticed you're stuck with Boost 1.33.1, which doesn't have Asio.  Well, if you're allowed to use other libraries you can use the [non-boost version](http://think-async.com/Asio) of Asio, or else you'll need to rely on OS-specific techniques to implement asynchronous timers.  You don't specify your OS, but on POSIX-compliant systems you can use select/poll for timeouts.

Actually, you can also use a background thread which sleeps until the next piece of data expires, then wakes up and checks the state of all the data, and goes back to sleep until the next piece of data expires.  You'd just need to be careful that you synchronize everything properly to avoid race conditions.

Comment: "Actually, you can also use a background thread which sleeps until the next piece of data expires" - I have this at the moment, but it doesn't allow for triggering events as data expires, e.g. the thread is sleeping for data A, data B arrives and times out, thread wakes after data A has expired. Data B never triggered an event.